# How to remove the prepend / append element from the DOM without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap popover and i wanted to add certain elements to the DOM. I am adding an additional element to the title using:

```
$('div.popover').prepend($('<h3>').html('Accounts Already exists').addClass('main-header-title'));
$('.main-header-title').append('<span class="close" id="cross-button">&times;</span>');
```

However if i dont refresh the page, the `('div.popover')` keeps prepending the `<h3>` element and i have duplicate titles seen in the popover. something like screenshot below:

[image]

Can anyone help me in setting the element to null, so that when i search again ( w/o refresh), it wont show me duplicate title names.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only append when its not already present in the DOM using

```
if ($('h3.main-header-title').length==0) {
     $('div.popover').prepend($('<h3>').html('Accounts Already exists').addClass('main-header-title'));
     $('.main-header-title').append('<span class="close" id="cross-button">&times;</span>');
}
```

You can achieve this using javascript only by

```
var element =  document.getElementsByClassName("main-header-title");
if (element.length ==0)
{
 $('div.popover').prepend($('<h3>').html('Accounts Already exists').addClass('main-header-title'));
         $('.main-header-title').append('<span class="close" id="cross-button">&times;</span>');
}
```

Or you can remove them after some time (say 1sec) when they are added to DOM

```
setTimeout(function(){
$("h3.main-header-title").remove();
// or $("h3.main-header-title").fadeOut(100); for animated removal
},1000);
```

And for better UX if you want to re-display the popover, do it this way.

```
if ($('h3.main-header-title').length==0) {
         $('div.popover').prepend($('<h3>').html('Accounts Already exists').addClass('main-header-title'));
         $('.main-header-title').append('<span class="close" id="cross-button">&times;</span>');
    }
else {
         $(h3.main-header-title).fadeOut(200);
         setTimeout(function(){$(h3.main-header-title).fadeIn(200);},500)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Read the updated answer, the other way is dont remove the popover automatically and when you want to show the popover again just remove the first popover and after 500ms re-display that for better UX.